# Hanging on vs To hang on

Tags: present-participles, modifiers

> [Error Correction ]

> The right wall of my bedroom had nothing ( hanging on，except a clock) .

> A. except a clock hanging

> B. to be hanging on，except acloc k

> C. to hang on，except a clock

> D. except a clock to be hung

Given answer: c

Is the original version incorrect because there should be a "it" after "on"？
Does the meaning remain the same  when C is substituted？

Comment: None of these seem idiomatic to me. _[The wall] had nothing hanging on it except a clock._ would make sense.

Comment: "the wall had nothing to hang on" would mean that, for some reason, *the wall* had to be hung, and it had nothing on which to be hung, except for on a clock.

Comment: Thank you both. I get it. C doesn't make sense even if it is grammatically correct -  it would suggest the wall is going to be hung on something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think any of these are correct. I would say:

> The right wall of my bedroom had nothing **hanging on it** except a clock.